# Filter both master and details record and include details in master

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

Please consider this scanrio:

I have a `Master` table:

```
Id        Country
--------------------
1         Ireland
2         Germany
3         Japan
```

and `Detials` table:

```
Id       MasterId         SellAmount
------------------------------------
 1          1               1000
 2          1               2000
 3          1               3000
 4          2               500
 5          2               1500
 6          2               4000
 7          3               5000
 8          3               5500
 9          3               1000
 10         3               2000
```

There is a foreign key between these tow table. I want to filter both master and details tables. For example:

```
Master Id >= 2  
Details SellAmount >= 3000
```

I want to inclsude those details records that have above criteria.

I wrote this query:

```
var list = (from m in Master.Where(r=>r.Id >= 2).Include("Details")
            join d in Details.Where(t=>t.SellAmount >= 3000)
              on m.Id equals d.MasterId                            
            select m).ToList();
```

but it returned all 6 master records!!!! Although In those master records I had all details record and filtering didn't take place.

How can I have this result:

```
2      Germany
                6          2               4000
3      Japan
                7          3               5000
                8          3               5500
```

Thanks

Comment: Use a where clause and remove the filters in the from and join

Comment: @GHDevOps: Yes, we can do this too but I don't think it will give me my desire result. above query isn't wrong.

Comment: Your sell amount is probably a string.  Try : Where(t=>int.Parse(t.SellAmount) >= 3000)

Comment: EF Core deals with objects, not tables and records. If your `Country` entity (not master) has a `SellAmounts` collection, EF Core itself will generate the JOINs as needed. If the classes and properties follow naming conventions you may not even have to configure the relations. In the [EF Core Getting Started](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/overview/first-app?tabs=netcore-cli) article, the Blog and Post relations are inferred from the types and names, eg `Blog.Posts` defines a 1:M relation between Blog and Post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Join operator multiplicate data if there is more than one record for joined pair.

If you use EF Core, rewrite your query using appropriate `Include`:

```cs
var list = Master
    .Include(r => r.Details.Where(t => t.SellAmount >= 3000))
    .Where(r => r.Id >= 2)
    .ToList();
```

With EF6 it is needed custom projection via `Select` into DTO class

```cs
var list = Master
    .Where(r => r.Id >= 2)
    .Select(r => new MasterDTO
    {
        Id = r.Id,
        Country = r.Country
        Details = r.Details.Where(t => t.SellAmount >= 3000).ToList()
    })
    .ToList();
```